# How do I vertically center an image in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Suppose the image is 100w x 300h.  But I have a div that is always 100x100.  I want to center the image (so that the top and bottom get cut off)

Note: The height will always be variable. It's not always 300.

How can I do that in JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just set the image as a background property of the div?  Straight CSS solution, no `js` necessary:

```
.cutoffAndCentered { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center; }
```

Or you can always do the same via jQuery:

```
$('.myDiv').css('background','url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use display: table-cell and overflow:hidden;
This tutorial should help http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html